# How use an annotation's value to initialize a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have below annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Import(MyBeanInitializer.class)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

String clientType() default "" ;

}
```

And I have a Bean initialiser component as below

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanInitializer {

@Bean() // trigger this when annoattion's value == "A"
public CommonBean firstBean() {
    return new BeanA;

}

@Bean() // trigger this when annoattion's value == "B"
public CommonBean firstBean() {
    return new BeanB;

}
}
```

My Commoin interface for BeanA and BeanB

```
public interface CommonBean {
void doSomething();
}
```

And my Two Implementations are

```
@Component()
public class BeanA implements CommonBean {

 @Overrid
 public void doSomething (){
 // implementation here
 }
}



@Component()
public class BeanB implements CommonBean {

 @Overrid
 public void doSomething (){
 // implementation here
 }
}
```

I need to use above as an library for another Spring Boot project. In that project I annotate `Application.java` with `@MyAnnotation(clientType="web")` and then I inject **BeanA** or **BeanB** to a class inside that project by using constructor Injection.

What is the mechanism to initialise beans by looking at the values passed through the annotation?

Comment: can you share the code where you want the bean to be injected? And most importantly both bean are of different types. `BeanA` and `BeanB`, do you plan to move them to a single Interface? It's not clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: Annotation's value is A/B _where_? Nothing is annotated with `MyAnnotation` in your example.

Comment: Also, Spring already has `@Conditional` for conditional definitions.

Comment: @iam.Carrot I have added the use case of this to the end.

Comment: @DinethSenevirathne Since `BeanA` and `BeanB` are two different `DataTypes` can you please share what exactly are you trying to do? You've shared `The How` but we want to know `The Why`. What is it that you're trying to achieve? Maybe give an example of what the condition would be and what what would happen when the condition is `true` and what would happen if the condition is `false`. How would you use the two different `datatypes`? Is there a common `interface` you've declared that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @iam.Carrot Sorry for the inconvenience this is my first time doing this kind of thing. I have added my interface and implementations to the code.

Comment: @DinethSenevirathne One last question, you'd want to only return one type of bean in a single application `Runtime`? Meaning would you be switching between the two implementations while running the application? or would you change the value of the annotation and then restart the application

Comment: Yes. I use just one bean at a time. If i want to initialize stop the application, then change the annotation value and re run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an annotation value for this.

Annotation values are hard-coded at compile time and cannot be dynamically changed.  Plus, it would look and feel *incredibly* awkward in the face of [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html), which already exists and ties into the ability to get *dynamic* properties.

What you want to do is use either a combination of `@Conditional` which allows you to define what you want to do given a specific environment variable, or use the [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation found in **Spring Boot** to simply provide the ability to wire in a bean based on the presence of a specific value in a specific property.

Here's how that'd look.  Let's assume that you have properties called `common.basicImpl` and `common.advancedImpl`.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "common", value = "basicImpl")
public class BeanA implements CommonBean {

 @Override
 public void doSomething (){
 // implementation here
 }
}



@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "common", value = "advancedImpl")
public class BeanB implements CommonBean {

 @Override
 public void doSomething (){
 // implementation here
 }
}
```

Note that this alone wouldn't resolve a circumstance in which *both* properties were present, and you can't do multiple `@ConditionalOnProperty` statements.  Adding [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) to be sure you don't accidentally wire up both of them at the same time would help you out there.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the suggestion. But in my case inside logics of basicImpl and advancedImpl are different. Even both have same input parameters each implementation uses different values from them. 
Could you mention the way of using annotation’s value to initialize the bean?

Comment: I don't understand the question @DinethSenevirathne.  So long as both beans implement `CommonBean` and the common interface of `CommonBean` is leveraged, it doesn't matter what the implementation details are to Spring.  It also does sound like this question is a bit of a tangent as well...

Comment: Hi, I try to use above implementation as a library to another project (main project). That means I make above implementation (I took your approach -ConditionalOnProperty and above implementation has no Application.java) then build jar file, then import into Main project, add properties and inject BeanA or BeanB. But it says that "No beans of BeanA found" when I try to inject inside Main project.

Comment: @DinethSenevirathne:  Crank up the debug logs and investigate what's going on there.  Chances are *pretty* good that the code which is using this as a library doesn't have the property set, so it's not capable of establishing which bean to wire in.

Comment: Solved! Thanks. I made it to work using the answer provided.